# ListView Inside Layout

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

I need some help creating a listview inside a layout i have. im having torubles creating it properly.

Here is what i got so far.

```
item.xml

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
        android:src="@drawable/gs3ultimate" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thelistarray"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thelistarry_details"
            android:textColor="#555555"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now its just a image on the left, then 2 textview, Now i believe im gonna need 2 string arrys, one for the titles and the 2nd for the details. and i think a 3rd one for the images. Is that right?

```
 Here some java for my list view
```

AndroidListViewActivity.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] list_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_array);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.label, list_array));



    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {


         }
       });
      }
   }
```

I know that my java is missing adding the details list_array_details. and i dont know how to add it so it populates. Im not yet using the onitemclick yet for my intent's. However would i determine which one is click and what activity to launch? example. i click list item b and want to like activity "b" but when i click a it launches activity "a"

Any help would be greately appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to understand what exactly you want us to help you with. Looks like there are just too much things you don't get. I'd advice you to go with some reading before actually writing code.

Comment: It's all on this site: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview

Comment: try to be a little bit clear so that one or the other would help you.

Comment: I apologize guys, i quickly wrote up this question, Thanks for at least taking a look at it @Sharath G

Comment: you too @Egor thanks for the try ill write the question better next time.

Comment: There's no hurry to write a question dude... Just try to make others understand what you want to say which will yield you better results.
You can just edit the question here itself

Comment: Thanks @ Chris Conway ill checkout the example code

Comment: Yeah let me re write the question real quick @Sharath G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a custom adapter for this purpose to populate someother view other than a textview or multiple textviews.

Take a look on customadapter [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/custom-list-view.html) and [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/Data/Adapters/Create_a_Custom_Adapter_for_Contacts)